# Additive merge of two arrays of objects with matching on non matching keys

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays (A and B) of objects that I need to combine and merge into a new array C. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

1. If an object appears in A but not in B, I need it copied into C without modification.
2. If an object appears in B but not in A, I need it copied into C without modification.
3. If an object appears in both A and B, I need all properties from A copied into B. If any properties appear in B that are not in A, I need them to remain in B. If any properties are shared between A and B, I need the B properties to overwrite the A properties.

I have tried a combination of Object.assign and Lodash merge to achieve the goals above.

```
merge(form.layout, updates.layout || {});
form.layout = Object.assign(updates.layout, form.layout);
```

form.layout: "A"

```
[
    {
        "key": "hidden-88539736345",
        "defaultField": true,
        "mandatoryField": true,
        "title": "Input",
        "type": "hidden",
        "id": "1180986379036",
        "allowOverride": true
    },
    {
        "key": "first-name",
        "allowOverride": true,
        "appearance": "outline",
        "autocomplete": "off",
        "dataType": "text",
        "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
        "defaultField": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "floatLabel": "always",
        "panelWidth": " ",
        "htmlClass": "   ",
        "id": "175813500463",
        "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
        "mandatoryField": false,
        "title": "first name",
        "title_revert": "Input",
        "type": "text"
    }
]
```

updates.layout: "B"

```
[
  {
    name: 'first-name',
    key: 'first-name',
    type: "text",
    title: 'First Name - UPDATED TITLE from updateLayout()',
    description: 'Description added by updateLayout()',
    appearance: "outline"
  },
  {
    name: 'date-test',
    key: 'date-test',
    title: "Date Field - NEW FIELD from updateLayout()",
    appearance: "outline",
    floatLabel: "always",
    "validationMessages": {
      "matDatepickerParse": "Invalid Date Format"
    }
  }
]
```

Final Output array "C":

```
[
    {
        "defaultField": true,
        "key": "first-name",
        "mandatoryField": true,
        "title": "First Name - UPDATED TITLE from updateLayout()",
        "type": "text",
        "id": "1180986379036",
        "allowOverride": true,
        "description": "Description added by updateLayout()",
        "appearance": "outline"
    },
    {
        "key": "date-test",
        "allowOverride": true,
        "appearance": "outline",
        "autocomplete": "off",
        "dataType": "text",
        "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
        "defaultField": true,
        "disabled": false,
        "floatLabel": "always",
        "panelWidth": " ",
        "htmlClass": "   ",
        "id": "175813500463",
        "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
        "mandatoryField": false,
        "title": "Date Field - NEW FIELD from updateLayout()",
        "title_revert": "Input",
        "type": "text",
        "description": "Description added by updateLayout()",
        "validationMessages": {
            "matDatepickerParse": "Invalid Date Format"
        }
    }
]
```

First, the `hidden-88539736345` field did not get copied over into the new array. The expected result is that the `hidden-88539736345` field should have been added to the merged array as is.

Also, the "date-test" field should have been copied over as is but somehow it has been merged with the "first-name" field.

I need to modify my approach to achieve the goals 1-3 above.

Here is the Array C I am trying to achieve:

```
[
  {
    "key": "hidden-88539736345",
    "defaultField": true,
    "mandatoryField": true,
    "title": "Input",
    "type": "hidden",
    "id": "1180986379036",
    "allowOverride": true
  },
  {
    "key": "first-name",
    "allowOverride": true,
    "appearance": "outline",
    "autocomplete": "off",
    "dataType": "text",
    "debounceCustomEventDelay": 0,
    "defaultField": true,
    "disabled": false,
    "floatLabel": "always",
    "panelWidth": " ",
    "htmlClass": "   ",
    "id": "175813500463",
    "itemsLayoutWidth": " ",
    "mandatoryField": false,
    "title": "First Name - UPDATED TITLE from updateLayout()",
    "title_revert": "Input",
    "description": 'Description added by updateLayout()',
    "type": "text"
  },
  {
    "name": 'date-test',
    "key": 'date-test',
    "title": "Date Field - NEW FIELD from updateLayout()",
    "appearance": "outline",
    "floatLabel": "always",
    "validationMessages": {
      "matDatepickerParse": "Invalid Date Format"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: "*If an object appears in A but not in B*" - since they are apparently distinct objects, how do you identify (compare) them? By their `key`?

Comment: "*I need all properties from A copied into B*" but also "*I need the B properties to overwrite the A properties.*" - so you essentially want to swap the values of properties that exist on both objects? Also do I understand correctly that you want to modify (mutate) the objects in the input arrays, but copy neither of them into the output array C?

Comment: If A and B have two objects with the same key, I need all of that object's properties copied into B, but any matching properties get overwritten by the property of the B object. Even though they are the same key, the properties may be different and A likely has more props than B

Comment: You mean you want to create a new object for array C that does have all the properties of B where A has a property with the same name, all the properties of A where B has no property with the same name, and none of the properties that B has but A doesn't?

Comment: Would it help if I updated the question and added the array C that I need from the merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we add in all objects from the first array that do not appear in the second.

Then, for each object in `b`, we look for an object in the first array with the same key as the object in `b`. If there is no match, the `??` operator returns an empty object, meaning that a merge will end up placing the object from `b` unmodified in the final array.

We merge these two objects together using spread syntax. Any properties from `b` will overwrite any properties with the same name found in `a`.

```js
const a = [{"key":"hidden-88539736345","defaultField":true,"mandatoryField":true,"title":"Input","type":"hidden","id":"1180986379036","allowOverride":true},{"key":"first-name","allowOverride":true,"appearance":"outline","autocomplete":"off","dataType":"text","debounceCustomEventDelay":0,"defaultField":true,"disabled":false,"floatLabel":"always","panelWidth":" ","htmlClass":"   ","id":"175813500463","itemsLayoutWidth":" ","mandatoryField":false,"title":"first name","title_revert":"Input","type":"text"}]
const b = [{"name":"first-name","key":"first-name","type":"text","title":"First Name - UPDATED TITLE from updateLayout()","description":"Description added by updateLayout()","appearance":"outline"},{"name":"date-test","key":"date-test","title":"Date Field - NEW FIELD from updateLayout()","appearance":"outline","floatLabel":"always","validationMessages":{"matDatepickerParse":"Invalid Date Format"}}]

const c = [
  ...a.filter(i => !b.some(j => j.key===i.key)),
  ...b.map(i => ({...a.find(j => j.key===i.key) ?? {}, ...i}))
]

console.log(c)
```

Comment: Andrew Parks - +1, I would never have guessed using filter and map. I did have to update from es5 to es6 and add some additional type specifications to my partialUpdates interface, but your solution looks to be good so far with testing.

Comment: Andrew, excellent! thanks for explaining the answer. I may post a second if I need help with a minor mod. That is to filter out any "A" fields that are (not in B && not denoted as required fields). Do you have a channel I can follow?

Comment: @ScottB I'm not sure what a channel is, but you can tag me in a comment here when you post a related question, so I'll be notified of it

Comment: Sounds good. What I meant to ask is if you have a Youtube channel, blog or similar where you share your knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottB oh lol, I'm not that interesting :) What's in my answer is fairly basic ES6 stuff

Comment: I'm just learning es6 syntax, basic or not, your solution came quick, is elegant in its simplicity and just plain does exactly what I asked. Couple ?s: (1) Using spread operator insures b properties ovewrite a? (2) Because of the spread syntax, you had to use a comma to chain the filter to the map?

Comment: @ScottB 1) If I do `let obj = {x:5, y:6, x:7}`, the last property declaration wins, the object is `{x:7, y:6}`. 2) That spread operator is for constructing a single object from the properties of two objects. E.g. `let a = {x:6, y:7}; let b = {x:8, z:9}; let c = {...a, ...b};` then `c` will be `{x:8, y:7, z:9}`. Then there is the spread inside the array that constructs one big array from the elements of the other arrays, returned by filter and map

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253404/discussion-between-scott-b-and-andrew-parks).